# IConfidentialClientApplication GetAccountsAsync returns nothing

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to make the Azure AD B2C demo work with my Azure AD.  This has two projects - TaskService and TaskWebApp.  I got the Web App part to work.  It directs me to the correct login page.  I'm using b2clogin.com instead of login.microsoftonline.com.  If I go to the claims page in the web app, everything appears ok.  When I try to use the TaskService (To-Do List), though, it fails in TaskController.

First it gets into OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, and the token and claims look correct.  AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode returns a token, and the comment says it should be cached.  Then it gets into the TaskController function (Index), and it creates another ConfidentialClientApplication.  Then it calls GetAccountsAsync and that returns an empty list.  There is no error and I have no idea why.  This causes the next line to fail, with a reasonable error messsage:
"No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call."
Because it is passing an empty list as the second parameter.

This results in the browser just looping between the login page and the web app a bunch of times until it decides to stop.

```
// Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
var scope = new string[] { Globals.ReadTasksScope };

IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync(); //this returns empty
AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync(); //this throws exception
```

I'm not sure what would cause me to have no accounts when I do have a current ClaimsPrincipal.
EDIT: I did notice that in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, my AuthenticationResult has almost everything filled in, but not Account.Username.  Would that matter?  If so, why would it not be filled in?

Comment: Which b2c demo are you trying to use to work with your Azure AD? AAD B2C and AAD are very different and it's not just a simple changing of tenant ids and client ids.

Comment: @FrankHuMSFT Even though we are changing all the app settings in the web config files, we are getting the username : Missing from the token response Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to these tutorials:

1. [Active Directory B2C Tutorials Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app)
2. [Active Directory B2C Tutorials Web Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-api)

And the related [GitHub Project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) (master branch, commit bf3bcce)

I had the same problem. TaskWebApp works fine, but accessing the Tasks view that relies on TaskWebApi results in an auth loop. Here's what I found, and how to make it work.

---

**TL;DR**

In the Web.config for the TaskWebApp project, add the following line in configuration/appSettings:

```
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="[your AAD B2C Tenant GUID here]" />
```

Save, build, and run. You should get past this auth loop.

---

**Details**

In Visual Studio, I set a breakpoint on TasksController.cs line 29:

```
var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
```

I can verify that this LOC is hit whenever I navigate to /Tasks. Stepping into each LOC called following that, I reviewed each part of the call stack to see where a null was being returned.

- GetAccountsAsync()
- {external code}
- TaskWebApp.Utils.MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache .UserTokenCacheBeforeAccessNotification(TokenClassNotification) NOT NULL
- .LoadUserTokenCacheFromMemory() NOT NULL
- .GetMsalAccountID() NOT NULL
- TaskWebApp.Utils.ClaimPrincipalExtension.GetB2CMsalAccountId(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal) **NULL!**

Specifically, line 40 in TaskWebApp\Utils\ClaimsPrincipalExtension.cs returns null.

```
string tenantId = Globals.TenantId;
```

It's assigning a tenant ID from Globals class defined in TaskWebApp Web.config, but it uses a value from key "ida:TenantId" that is not supplied anywhere.